# MKS si resync returns 5

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

While trying to resync using si resync, we are getting an **error** says:

`"MKS125216 The sandbox file sandbox_path_here/project.pj is not registered with the system."`

When i tried on another sandbox whihc i had in my local the same command worked.

Any idea what this **error** says:

`MKS125216 The sandbox file sandbox_path_here/project.pj is not registered with the system.`

Help with your inputs.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause of this error:**
As of now the sandbox from which you are trying to do is resync is just a folder in your system, it have to be registered in mks to make it as recognizable by MKS as Sandbox(MKS understandable structure).

**What this exit code 5 means:**
Build from Sandbox_location exiting with error code 5: 
Means Unable to create or utilize the selection of command.

**How to find Root Cause for this error:**
go to `mks/bin directory/si sandboxes.`

above command will list out all existing sandboxes in your local machine (from where you are trying to run resync) and its mapping to projects in MKS repository server.

If the sandbox location for which you are running resync is not listed there means , it is not yet registered to MKS Repository.

**Prerequisite to run si resync:** the sandbox for which you are running resync should be registered in MKS Repository Server Machine.

**how to fix this**
If you are Using Windows machine and have a MKS Web UI: create a new sandbox with the location of sandbox as the current location of sandbox you are trying to do resync.

If linux : go to location of your current sandboxfolder.

from that location point to `MKS/bin/si createsandbox -R --host=yourhostname  --pw=***`

it will create/register your local folder as sandbox with MKS Rep Server.

**How to Verify it it registered Correctly**
si sandboxes
Results should contan your new sandbox.. :)

Happy Working and All the Best